# Why do Facebook left-navigation items disappear if I'm logged in as an admin?

Tags: facebook

I have 14 items in the left-side navigation of my Facebook page.

If I'm not logged in, or if I'm logged in with a non-admin account, I see the first 8 items and I can click a More link to show the additional 6 items, then click a Less link to hide the additional items.

If I'm logged in as an admin, only the top 8 items are visible, and there isn't a More link. If I go directly to the URL of one of the 6 items that aren't visible, I can see all of the navigation items, but there still aren't More or Less links.

How can I restore the More or Less links and see all of the items in the left navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19868

As a temporary workaround try changing *www.facebook.com* to *beta.facebook.com* in the URL.

Comment: Should be fixed now.